# C HTTPS request returns 0 on recv, HTTP works

Tags: c++, sockets, https, client

I am writing a simple downloader in C++, it works fine with making HTTP requests to port 80, but now I have been trying to update the code to make requests and download files from HTTPS and my recv method always returns length 0. I tried to change headers different ways and verified it with Postman, and those headers work fine. Don't understand what is happening.

In my code I first send a HEAD request to the server to find out the size of the file to be downloaded and even the HEAD request doesn't come back

Here is my sendRequest method

```
void Client::sendRequest() {

ptr = request.c_str();
nleft = request.length();
// write the data to the server
while (nleft) {
    if ((nwritten = send(s, ptr, nleft, 0)) < 0) {
        if (errno == EINTR) {
            // the socket call was interrupted -- try again
            nwritten = 0;
        } else {
            // an error occurred, so break out
            perror("write");
            break;
        }
    } else if (nwritten == 0) {
        cout << "the socket is closed" << endl;
        // the socket is closed
        break;
    }
    nleft -= nwritten;
    ptr += nwritten;
 }
}
```

After sending a request I am reading the response in this method:

```
string Client::readResponse() {
// read the response
char buf[1024];
memset(buf, 0, 1024);
string downloaded;

while (true) {
    long nread = recv(s, buf, 1024, 0);
    downloaded.append(buf, nread);
    if(downloaded.size() != 0) {
        //check for \r\n\r\n to know it's the end of the header
        if (downloaded.at(downloaded.length() - 1) == 10
            && downloaded.at(downloaded.length() - 3) == 10) {
            break;
        }
    }

 }
 return downloaded;
}
```

nread always return 0 for HEAD requests on urls with HTTPS (e.g. "https://medpix.nlm.nih.gov/images/full/synpic54731.jpg"). 
Really not sure what is happening. 
Header for request to http://services.hanselandpetal.com/selfie%20dogs-488938505.jpg

```
"HEAD /selfie%20dogs-488938505.jpg HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: services.hanselandpetal.com\r\n\r\n"
```

Header for request to the https url above:

```
"HEAD /images/full/synpic54731.jpg HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: medpix.nlm.nih.gov\r\n\r\n"
```

Comment: Do you know how HTTPS is different from HTTP?

Comment: Do you mean different ports? 80/443, not encrypted/encrypted, certificate not required/required? I kind of understand the difference (no sarcasm), just not sure what exactly I am missing or need to implement additionally for this downloader to work. Postman doesn't have a certificate and it can make head requests. or am I missing something here?

Comment: You are missing a lot. HTTPS means HTTP over TLS, not just HTTP. So you need to open a socket and then speak TLS to the server (instead of speaking HTTP), and then once you have a TLS connection set up you can speak HTTP "inside" that connection.

Comment: Also, while you can write your own HTTP code, it will not be practical to write your own TLS code.

Comment: Also, it is not possible for a TLS server to not have a certificate.

Comment: @immibis: nitpicking, but actually it is possible to use TLS without certificates (like with ADH or SRP ciphers). But it is very uncommon because you have to take care yourself about proper authentication of the server then.

Comment: It's better to use `libcurl` to perform such operations instead of directly using raw socket.

Comment: If you are going to write your own socket code, at least use a pre-existing security library to handle the SSL/TLS portion on top of it, like OpenSSL, Boost::Asio, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for the input! do you know of any good references on how to use OpenSSL with own sockets? I just need a starting point. Thank you!

Comment: @arubin if you want to use your own socket I/O, you have to use OpenSSL's BIO API to push data into the crypto engine and read it out. If you let OpenSSL handle the socket I/O for you, you can use its SSL API instead. Plenty of examples floating around.